# Reconstructing a Random Process from Moments

Tags: stochastic-processes

If I had the moments of a single random variable $ X $, then I could compute the distribution by Laplace transforming the generating function,

$$\begin{align}
\rho(X) &= \mathcal{L}^{-1} \big\{ \mathbb{E}[ e^{-sX} ] \big\} \\
  &= \mathcal{L}^{-1} \big\{ \sum_n \frac{(-s)^n \mathbb{E}[ X^n ]}{n!} \big\}
\end{align}$$

So in effect, if I have all the moments, I have the p.d.f. Of course it's not so simple, but that's the idea.

I have an "auto-correlated" random process $ B_t $ that has moments like,

$$
\mathbb{E}\big[ (B_t - B_s)^n \big] = f_n(s - t)
$$

I know all the moments, but how to I reconstruct the random process?

Comment: Under some mild assumptions (which you implicitly make in the first half of your post), the moments provide all finite marginal distributions of the process.  Apply the [Kolmogorov Extension Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_extension_theorem).

Comment: @whuber Could you offer any good references on using this for process reconstruction?